# non interactive input to interactive bash command failing

Tags: bash

Hi the following bash command works on my terminal in mac but fails when run on the terminal in docker:

```
#!/bin/sh
{ echo "ar"; sleep 1; echo "br"; } | ./4icli configure

Please enter your API Client ID:
Please enter your API Client Secret:
Validating credentials...
An error occurred validating these credentials. Request failed with status code 400
```

This same command fails on the docker terminal with the following error:

```
Please enter your API Client ID: sh: 1: read: Illegal option -s
```

Very puzzled how to get around this issue.

Comment: Do you have any visibility into what 4icli is doing? Can you see what payload it's sending?

Comment: `read -s` is a bash extension. `/bin/sh` is not guaranteed to offer it -- only the behavior documented in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html is portable.

Comment: Some commands that  read passwords specifically ignore stdin (such as ssh). If that's the case, you may need to use [tag:expect]

Comment: Note that the actual problem is in the `4icli` script, not the one given above (and as Charles Duffy said, the problem is that `4icli` depends on bash extensions, but is running under a non-bash shell).

Comment: @GordonDavisson The 4icli is a binary. I can get it to work on my MAC which is running bash version: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19) The docker image I am running under is python-3.9-slim_buster which has a much later version of bash 5.* something

Comment: I tried using expect but was UN-successful since the 4icli tool asks for input (user - passwd) and when one input is given it prints out the same statement but with masked (**) value that I entered, this confuses Expect, that is the reason I put a sleep 1 in between the two inputs and this works.
`anna@sh1052 partner-service % ./4icli configure
Please enter your API Client ID: **
Please enter your API Client Secret: **
Validating credentials...
`

Comment: What is your docker `FROM` line? from there you could google how to make sh bash in that OS

Comment: @punyakoti, binary though it may be, from the error message, it's clearly one that starts `sh` during its operation. The version of bash you have is irrelevant if the binary is starting sh instead; you need to compare versions of sh, not versions of bash.

Comment: Note that sh is what's started by `system()` and similar calls; if someone used bash-only syntax in an argument passed to such a call, that's a bug on the part of the author of that software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sh: 1: read: Illegal option -s
```

In  bash, `-s` is silent mode for `read`.  But often docker does not ship with bash as the default shell.

The solution depends the distribution behind the docker container and whether you can make `sh` be bash or whether you have to alter the script

Comment: Not just docker -- there are major distros (Debian, Ubuntu, etc) where `/bin/sh` is ash or dash. (Or on NixOS, which I use, it can be bash compiled _without_ optional interactive extensions).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In the docker image I have sh, bash, dash all of them included under /bin/.

Comment: "`sh: 1:`" we can conclude that at least the apparent name of the invoked shell is `sh`.  You may *have* `bash` but the `sh` that's running clearly is not bash, or at least not in the expected configuration.  It seems likely that `4icli` assumes `sh` will end up being `bash` , as is shown in your Mac OS terminal.